# Appwrite with Flutter, Google OAuth provider issue

Tags: flutter, oauth, riverpod, appwrite

i'm trying to add Google OAuth provider of **Appwrite** into a Flutter app (use Riverpod for state managment). With email and password I can login/register and push to home_view.dart
With Google after login, I correctly see the user data on Appwrite but received the ***session*** variable **null** and not redirect to home_view.dart (because session variable null).
Then, when I press hot-reload I see the home_view.dart with user google logged.

Would someone be so kind to help me? Thank you so much.

**auth_api.dart**

```
final authAPIProvider = Provider((ref) {
  final account = ref.watch(appwriteAccountProvider);
  return AuthAPI(account: account);
});

abstract class IAuthAPI {
  FutureEither<model.User> signUp({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  });
  FutureEither<model.Session> login({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  });
    FutureEither<model.Session> loginWithGoogle();
  Future<model.User?> currentUserAccount();
  FutureEitherVoid logout();
}

class AuthAPI implements IAuthAPI {
  final Account _account;
  AuthAPI({required Account account}) : _account = account;

  @override
  Future<model.User?> currentUserAccount() async {
    try {
      return await _account.get();
    } on AppwriteException {
      return null;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  FutureEither<model.User> signUp({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      final account = await _account.create(
        userId: ID.unique(),
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return right(account);
    } on AppwriteException catch (e, stackTrace) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.message ?? 'Some unexpected error occurred', stackTrace),
      );
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.toString(), stackTrace),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  FutureEither<model.Session> login({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      final session = await _account.createEmailSession(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return right(session);
    } on AppwriteException catch (e, stackTrace) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.message ?? 'Some unexpected error occurred', stackTrace),
      );
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.toString(), stackTrace),
      );
    }
  }

    @override
  FutureEither<model.Session> loginWithGoogle(
  ) async {
    try {
      final session = await _account.createOAuth2Session(
        provider: 'google',
        success: "",
        failure: "",
      );
      debugPrint(session);
      return right(session);
    } on AppwriteException catch (e, stackTrace) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.message ?? 'Some unexpected error occurred', stackTrace),
      );
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.toString(), stackTrace),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  FutureEitherVoid logout() async {
    try {
      await _account.deleteSession(
        sessionId: 'current',
      );
      return right(null);
    } on AppwriteException catch (e, stackTrace) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.message ?? 'Some unexpected error occurred', stackTrace),
      );
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.toString(), stackTrace),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

and
**auth_controller.dart**

```
final authControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<AuthController, bool>((ref) {
  return AuthController(
    authAPI: ref.watch(authAPIProvider),
    userAPI: ref.watch(userAPIProvider),
  );
});

final currentUserDetailsProvider = FutureProvider((ref) {
  final currentUserId = ref.watch(currentUserAccountProvider).value!.$id;
  debugPrint("Utente corrente: $currentUserId");
  final userDetails = ref.watch(userDetailsProvider(currentUserId));
  return userDetails.value;
});

final userDetailsProvider = FutureProvider.family((ref, String uid) {
  final authController = ref.watch(authControllerProvider.notifier);
  return authController.getUserData(uid);
});

final currentUserAccountProvider = FutureProvider((ref) {
  final authController = ref.watch(authControllerProvider.notifier);
  return authController.currentUser();
});

class AuthController extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  final AuthAPI _authAPI;
  final UserAPI _userAPI;
  AuthController({
    required AuthAPI authAPI,
    required UserAPI userAPI,
  })  : _authAPI = authAPI,
        _userAPI = userAPI,
        super(false);
  // state = isLoading

  Future<model.User?> currentUser() => _authAPI.currentUserAccount();

  void signUp({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    state = true;
    final res = await _authAPI.signUp(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    state = false;
    res.fold(
      (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message),
      (r) async {
        UserModel userModel = UserModel(
          email: email,
          name: getNameFromEmail(email),
          followers: const [],
          following: const [],
          profilePic: '',
          bannerPic: '',
          uid: r.$id,
          bio: '',
          isTwitterBlue: false,
        );
        final res2 = await _userAPI.saveUserData(userModel);
        res2.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) {
          showSnackBar(context, 'Accounted created! Please login.');
          Navigator.push(context, LoginView.route());
        });
      },
    );
  }

  void login({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    state = true;
    final res = await _authAPI.login(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    state = false;
    res.fold(
      (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message),
      (r) {
        Navigator.push(context, HomeView.route());
      },
    );
  }

  void loginWithGoogle({
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    state = true;
    final res = await _authAPI.loginWithGoogle(
    );
    state = false;
    res.fold(
      (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message),
      (r) {
        Navigator.push(context, HomeView.route());
      },
    );
  }

  Future<UserModel> getUserData(String uid) async {
    final document = await _userAPI.getUserData(uid);
    final updatedUser = UserModel.fromMap(document.data);
    return updatedUser;
  }

  void logout(BuildContext context) async {
    final res = await _authAPI.logout();
    res.fold((l) => null, (r) {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        SignUpView.route(),
        (route) => false,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, where is your provider and what does he look like?

Comment: I edited with full file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. On auth_api.dart I removed <model.Session> from FutureEither<model.Session> loginWithGoogle and removed <model.Session> from FutureEither<model.Session> loginWithGoogle();

Answer (score 0):

yes, google doesn't return appwrites model.Session shape. It has its own. I was looking at your code and if you run a debugPrint after this line

```
final res = await _authAPI.loginWithGoogle();
debugPrint("$res"); // here you will see what gets returned by google
```